# What's the most efficient way to add (new) documents from a Dataframe to MongoDB?

Tags: python, pandas, mongodb, dataframe, pymongo

In this use case, I am trying to add documents to a MongoDB collection using pymongo that are retrieved from various RSS news feeds based on the date (not datetime), title, and article summary in dataframe format (the date being the index to the dataframe).

When I store the dataframe to the database, they are stored with the schema of _id, date, title, summary which is fine.

So what I'm trying to do is only upload those rows in the dataframe which haven't been stored as documents in the collection. There are a few ways I've tried:

1. Get the last document in the database, compare to the dataframe. Create a new DF which excludes all previous rows + the row its being compared to. This should work, however, it is still uploading roughly 20% of the rows which have been previously stored and I have no idea why.
2. Store the entire dataframe, then aggregate the collection and remove the duplicates: Sounds good in theory however all of the examples of doing this are in JS and not python, so I haven't been able to get this to work.
3. Create a unique index of the title: Again, this should work in theory, but I haven't gotten it to work.

One thing that I don't want to do is to query the entire collection and store as a DF, concatenate them, drop the duplicates, delete the collection, and re-create it from the new DF. It wouldn't be an issue now since I'm working with 30 or so documents, but when I'll be working with multiple collections and millions of documents, well.. not very efficient at all.

Anyone have any suggestions I can look into / research / code examples?

Here is the code I'm working with now:

## Download RSS Feed

```
def getSymbolNews(self, symbol):
    self.symbol = symbol
    self.dbName = 'db_' + self.symbol
    self.columnName = 'col_News'
    self.topics = ['$' + self.symbol]
    self.sa = getNews().parseNews(fn.SeekingAlpha(topics = self.topics))
    self.yfin = getNews().parseNews(fn.Yahoo(topics = self.topics))
    self.wb_news = getNews().getWebullNews(self.symbol)        
    self.df = pd.concat([self.sa, self.yfin, self.wb_news], axis = 0, ignore_index = False)
    self.df.drop_duplicates(inplace = True)
    self.df.sort_index(ascending = True, inplace = True)
    del self.symbol, self.topics, self.sa, self.yfin, self.wb_news
    getNews().uploadRecords(self.dbName, self.columnName, self.df)
    return self.df
```

## Upload to Collection:

```
def uploadRecords(self, dbName, columnName, data):
    self.data = data
    self.dbName = dbName
    self.columnName = columnName
    self.data.reset_index(inplace=True)
    self.data.rename(columns={'index': 'Date'}, inplace = True)
    mongoFunctions.insertRecords(self.dbName, self.columnName, self.data)
    del self.data
    gc.collect()
    return
```

## PyMongo function to upload:

```
def insertRecords(dbName: str, collectionName: str, data: object):
    """Inserts a pandas dataframe object into a MongoDB collection (table)

    Args:
        dbName (str): Database name
        collectionName (str): Collection name
        data (object): Pandas dataframe object
    """

    collection = getCollection(dbName, collectionName)
    query = queryAllRecords(dbName, collectionName)

    if query.shape == (0, 0):
        record = data.to_dict(orient="records")
        collection.insert(record)
    else:
        query.drop(["_id"], axis=1, inplace=True)
        if query.equals(data):
            return
        else:
            df_temp = pd.concat([query, data]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
            records = df_temp.to_dict(orient="records")
            collection.insert_many(records)

    return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be minded to take an `md5` hash of the document and store that as the `_id`; then you can just use `insert_many()` with `ordered=False` to insert any items that aren't duplicates; you can run this as often as you like and only new items will be added; bear in mind that if **any** field is even sligtly changed a new item is added; if this isn't the behaviour you want then tweak what you pass to `md5()`.

The code ends up being fairly straightforward:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pymongo.errors import BulkWriteError
import feedparser
from hashlib import md5
from json import dumps

db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']

entries = feedparser.parse("http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/world/rss.xml")['entries']

for item in entries:
    item['_id'] = md5(dumps(item).encode("utf-8")).hexdigest()

try:
    db.news.insert_many(entries, ordered=False)
except BulkWriteError:
    pass
```

Comment: That is actually a great idea that I didn't think of. Thank you!